# odbc excel java

Tags: java, excel, jdbc-odbc

I am using JDBC-ODBC DSN-less connection to connect to ms-excel file.
I was able to query the excel file using query of form

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]
```

However this requires me to know the name of the Sheet in excel file (which may not always be Sheet1). Is there any way I can query the excel to always hit its 1st sheet?

Comment: You can use `DatabaseMetaData.getTables` method.

Comment: @AVD what parameters should be used in getTables method? 4 nulls? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: Except third. e.g `dbMetaData.getTables(null, null, "%", null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
```

where con is your connection. On meta object you can call:

```
getSchema();
getTables(null, null, "%", null); // thanks to AVD
```

Both of the methods return ResultSets on which you can iterate to see what's inside. There is no guarantee that getTables() method [will return full data](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Maybe I quoted wrong methods, but I am sure you can find some in [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSchemas%28%29) class that will return what you need in case of excel.